# How to add watermark to all video files in a folder? (Mac, mencoder, terminal)

Tags: macos, mac, terminal, video, iterm

Is there a way to add watermark to all (mp4) video files in a folder.

I have like 1000 videos in one folder and It'll take a long time to change one by one manually - so, maybe, there is some kind of a tool / software?

Maybe, it's possible to do somehow with `mencoder` that I can run in terminal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do it from the terminal with ffmpeg's overlay filter ... [download prebuilt binaries](https://www.ffmpeg.org/download.html) or install with Homebrew if you don't have it already and the command would look something like this:

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex 'overlay=10:10' outputname.mp4
```

That'll place watermark.png 10px in and 10px down from the top right corner ...